# given a start date how to find the end date which have 365 or 366 days based on the leap year

Tags: c#, datetime

```
public static DateTime GetBudgetYearEndDateConsideringLeapYear(DateTime budgetYearStartDate)
    {
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        if (budgetYearStartDate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("budgetYearStartDate must be provided before calling this method");

        int startingDateMonth = budgetYearStartDate.Month;
        if (startingDateMonth > 2) /// Leap year for the starting year is escaped because  Month is NOT February
        {
            endDate = budgetYearStartDate.AddDays(365);
            bool isEndYearLeapYear = DateTime.IsLeapYear(endDate.Year);

            if (isEndYearLeapYear)
            {
                return endDate.AddDays(1);
            }
            return endDate;
        }
        else  // started from JAN/ FEB
        {
            if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(budgetYearStartDate.Year))
            {
                return budgetYearStartDate.AddDays(366);
            }
            return budgetYearStartDate.AddDays(365);
        }

    }
```

What am I missing here

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what kind of results this code is giving and what are you expecting exactly?

Comment: I think you've majorly over complicated the problem here.

Comment: Basically I am trying to find the end date given the start date such as '2011-01-02'; of course considering the leap year and stuff. Currently My method is returning 367 days if it is leap year otherwise 366 days

Comment: But what is the end date defined as? 1 Year?

Comment: @Shiva: Please give us some sample input and expected output values. It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve *unless* you're just trying to add a year - in which case, call AddYears.

Comment: DateTime is a value type, budgetYearStartDate will never be null.

Comment: End year is defined as either 365 days or 366 days from the start date  whether the year is leap or not

Comment: @Shiva: Don't think of it in terms of days. Think of it in terms of the *date* involved. Again, please give sample outputs. I suspect you're making this far more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `startDate.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);`?

This assumes that given a start date of July 1, you want an end date of June 30.  The example you posted suggests that you want July 1 -> July 1, in which case, it would be `startDate.AddYears(1);`.

Comment: Comment by anonymous user in suggested edit: `This code doesn't work for start date of 2/29/2012. The addyears will go to 2/28/2013 then the adddays -1 will end up returning 2/27/2013 which is not correct. I'd like an elegant solution that doesn't wrap this in an If, if anyone has one. Notice I am posting this on 2/28/2013 :(`

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with:

```
public static DateTime GetBudgetYearEndDateConsideringLeapYear
    (DateTime budgetYearStartDate)
{
    return budgetYearStartDate.AddYears(1);
}
```

? In other words, return the date a year from the start date, regardless of whether or not it's a leap year.

A couple of things to note:

- You should consider what you want the result to be if the start date is February 29th
- Your check for nullity is pointless, given that `DateTime` is a value type

Comment: Thanks for you reply Jon; does the AddYears(1) consider the leap year; In my case if it is the leap year; total days must be 366 days

Comment: Does it need to? 1 Year later than the 03/11/2011 is 03/11/2012 regardless of whether it's a leap year.

Comment: Yes it takes it in account: `The AddYears method calculates the resulting year taking into account leap years` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx

Comment: BTW. 29/02/2012 + 1 Year = 28/02/2013 (also 28/02/2012 + 1 Year = 28/02/2013)

Comment: Thank you all; You guys are awesome!! I just made my code complicated;

Answer (score 2):

[AddYears](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx) takes leap years into account so...

```
budgetYearEndDateConsideringLeapYear = budgetYearStartDate.AddYears(1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much; I did know that AddYears(1) considers the leap year:This method does not change the value of this DateTime object. Instead, it returns a new DateTime object whose value is the result of this operation.

The AddYears method calculates the resulting year taking into account leap years. The month and time-of-day part of the resulting DateTime object remains the same as this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime dtStartOfThisYear = new DateTime( 2011, 11 , 1 ) ;
DateTime dtStartOfNextYear = dtStartOfThisyear.AddYears(1) ;
```

If you crack open the `AddYears()` method in Reflector, you'll see that it just invokes the `AddMonths()` method, passing it the value `years * 12`. Clever, huh?

And if you crack open `AddMonths()`, you'll see

```
public DateTime AddMonths(int months)
{
    if ( ( months < -120000 ) || ( months > 0x1d4c0 ) )
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("months", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_DateTimeBadMonths"));
    }

    int datePart = this.GetDatePart( 0 ) ;
    int month    = this.GetDatePart( 2 ) ;
    int day      = this.GetDatePart( 3 ) ;

    int num4     = ( month - 1 ) + months ;
    if ( num4 >= 0 )
    {
        month     = ( num4 % 12 ) + 1 ;
        datePart += num4 / 12 ;
    }
    else
    {
        month     = 12 + ( ( num4 +  1 ) % 12 ) ;
        datePart +=        ( num4 - 11 ) / 12   ;
    }

    if ( ( datePart < 1 ) || ( datePart > 0x270f ) )
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("months", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_DateArithmetic"));
    }

    int num5 = DaysInMonth( datePart , month );
    if ( day > num5 )
    {
        day = num5 ;
    }

    return new DateTime(((ulong) (DateToTicks(datePart, month, day) + (this.InternalTicks % 0xc92a69c000L))) | this.InternalKind);
}
```

I believe you'll find that this code does what you want: for instance, if you start on 29 February of a leap year and add 1 year, you'll wind up on 28 February of the next year.